# Objective C: How to fix scanf() skipping over lines

Tags: objective-c, scanf

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *sg, *ge, *pr, *ln;
    NSString *done = @"";
    int actn = 0; 
    NSError *error;

    printf("Welcome to Your Playlist\n");

    while(actn != 6)
    {
        printf("\nWhat would you like to do?");
        printf("\n1. Enter a New Song, Performer, Genre, and the Length of the Song");
        printf("\n2. Show all Songs in Your Playlist");
        printf("\n3. Show all Songs in Your Playlist and Sort by Song Title");
        printf("\n4. Show all Songs in Your Playlist and Sort by Genre");
        printf("\n5. Show all Songs in Your Playlist and Sort by Performer");
        printf("\n6. Save and Quit\n");
        scanf("%d", &actn);

        if(actn == 1)
        {
            while([done isEqualToString:@"No"] == false)
            {
                printf("What is the Song Title? ");
                scanf("%@", &sg);

                printf("Who is the Performer? ");
                scanf("%@", &pr);

                printf("What is the Genre of this Song? ");
                scanf("%@", &ge);

                printf("What is the length of the Song? ");
                scanf("%@", &ln);

                printf("Would you like to quit(Yes or No)? ");        
                scanf("%@", &done);
        }   
    }  

    if(actn == 2)
    {
        NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"E:/Playlist" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

        if(error) 
        { 
            NSLog(@"ERROR while loading from file: %@", error);
        }

        [contents writeToFile:@"E:/Playlist" atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:&error];
        printf("%@",contents);
    }


    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

It allow to enter in a number, which I start off by typing in 1. It asks me to enter the title of a song. After that, it will infinitely keep printing out the next several lines in the while loop without asking me for input. How can I fix this?

Comment: `printf` and `scanf` are legacy C standard library functions - they don't know anything about Objective C objects such as `NSString`. You need to either use C strings (`char *`) or use suitable Objective C methods to read/write `NSString`s. Note also that the above code generates a ton of compiler warnings - did you just decide to ignore them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong format specifiers:

```
scanf("%@", &sg);
       ^^
```

As `scanf()` is a C-runtime library function, you cannot use `Foundation` types.  Instead you need to use a `char` array and the `%s` specifier, however OSX might support the `%ms` specifier, which is safer as it allocates a `char *` via `malloc()` so cannot be easily overflowed.

Comment: There is a buffer overflow vulnerability in your code.

Comment: @SiyuanRen Buffer overflow removed.  Now remove your downvote.